# changing styles in the tr of a table

Tags: html, css

I am creating a table with html and css, and I need the tr of the table to have a border with dots like the ones in this image
[image]

and also have that space at the beginning and end of the tr, I have this so far

```
<style>
  tr.tr_dotted td 
  {
      border-bottom: dotted 1.8px #bdbdbd !important
  }
</style>
```

but I don't know how to add that space at the beginning and end of the tr.

Comment: padding-left: 15px; or padding: 0 0 0 15px; maybe?

Comment: @OldPadawan no, dont work :/